# How do I group customers in to equal sets of revenue?

Tags: postgresql, function, window, percentile, quartile

really struggling to come up with an answer for this one. There are various functions which provide Ntiles. Often these provide equal sets of rows per ntile.

I require to group customers by (approximate) equal sets of revenue. This way I can show the customers responsible for the top 10% of revenue and next 10% etc

In other words, all customers are sorted by revenue and grouped in to deciles of revenue.

```
        create table test_set (name text, revenue numeric);

        insert into test_set values ('a1',234.34);
        insert into test_set values ('a2',263.60);
        insert into test_set values ('a3',316.99);
        insert into test_set values ('a4',351.68);
        insert into test_set values ('a5',353.07);
        insert into test_set values ('a6',406.33;
        insert into test_set values ('a7',432.78);
        insert into test_set values ('a8',444.88);
        insert into test_set values ('a9',452.21);
        insert into test_set values ('a10',543.75);
        insert into test_set values ('a11',582.43);
        insert into test_set values ('a12',670.98);
        insert into test_set values ('a13',720.46);
        insert into test_set values ('a14',801.69);
        insert into test_set values ('a15',803.92);
        insert into test_set values ('a16',821.03);
        insert into test_set values ('a17',875.57);
        insert into test_set values ('a18',930.95);
        insert into test_set values ('a19',973.49);
        insert into test_set values ('a20',1055.48);
        insert into test_set values ('a21',1059.01);
        insert into test_set values ('a22',1131.09);
        insert into test_set values ('a23',1215.51);
        insert into test_set values ('a24',1232.19);
        insert into test_set values ('a25',1310.59);
        insert into test_set values ('a26',1353.31);
        insert into test_set values ('a27',1368.28);
        insert into test_set values ('a28',1412.58);
        insert into test_set values ('a29',1412.38);
        insert into test_set values ('a30',1489.78);
        insert into test_set values ('a31',1496.31);
        insert into test_set values ('a32',1587.17);
        insert into test_set values ('a33',3629.34);
        insert into test_set values ('a34',4642.01);
        insert into test_set values ('a35',6682.07);
        insert into test_set values ('a36',752.70);
        insert into test_set values ('a37',3819.59);
        insert into test_set values ('a38',2857.22);
        insert into test_set values ('a39',873.45);
        insert into test_set values ('a40',882.42);
```

Hope someone can help... Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the expected output?

Comment: Are you expecting something like that? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=867e63f7232f1e57e26e88eaa0cf8dc8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cumulative `SUM()` window function might help:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=867e63f7232f1e57e26e88eaa0cf8dc8)

```
select
    name, revenue,
    sum(revenue) OVER () as total,
    sum(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY revenue) as cumulative,
    (sum(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY revenue) / sum(revenue) OVER () * 100) as cumulative_procent,
    trunc((sum(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY revenue) / sum(revenue) OVER () * 100) / 10) as group_by_tenth
from test_set
order by revenue
```

3. column: Calculates the total SUM of revenues
4. column: Calculates the cumulative SUM ordered by revenues
5. column: Takes both terms for calculating the increasing  procent value
6. column: For clustering you can trunct this result to tenth parts

Comment: S-MAN - thats great - I have enhanced slightly

Answer (score 0):

S-MAN - that's it... thank you so much. I have enhanced slightly

```
   ceil(((sum(sum(revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY sum(revenue)) / sum(sum(revenue)) OVER () * 100) /10)) as revenue_sets
```